# jquery not working in IE, form field "is undefined"

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer

I'm using jquery to strip commas from a form field on submit so the form plays nice with the next step. The jquery script works in Chrome and Firefox but not IE.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        $(price1).val( $(price1).val().replace(/,/g,'') );
    });
});</script>
```

and the form field is simply:

```
<input name="price1" id="price1"   value="" size="32">
```

What am I missing? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `$(price1)` to `$("#price1")`. Some browsers turn all IDs into global variables, but this isn't the standard way to access them.

Answer (score 0):

That worked! The commas are stripped and I actually understand your solution.  Thank you